I am getting this error when i run this command i am using macbook m1.Can anyone tell me what to do
npm install --save-dev @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle ethereum-waffle chai @nomiclabs/hardhat-ether ethers


npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: studentwelfare@0.1.0
npm WARN Found: ethers@5.7.2
npm WARN node_modules/ethers
npm WARN   dev ethers@"*" from the root project
npm WARN   3 more (@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle, ...)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer ethers@"^5.0.0" from @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle@2.0.6
npm WARN node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle
npm WARN   dev @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle@"*" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: studentwelfare@0.1.0
npm WARN Found: ethers@5.7.2
npm WARN node_modules/ethers
npm WARN   dev ethers@"*" from the root project
npm WARN   3 more (@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle, ...)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer ethers@"^5.0.0" from @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers@2.2.3
npm WARN node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers
npm WARN   peer @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers@"^2.0.0" from @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle@2.0.6
npm WARN   node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@nomiclabs%2fhardhat-ether - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@nomiclabs/hardhat-ether@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/aditya/.npm/_logs/2024-05-02T09_33_54_268Z-debug-0.log

i tried to install nomiclabs toolbox but it not work.

Looks like you're missing an s
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers
here you go S
